# How to find out whether there is a specific key for a given Lua table through C Apis besides traversing the whole table?

Tags: lua, lua-table

How to find out whether there is a specific key for a given Lua table through C Apis?

I know that traversing the whole table could achieve this goal, but it's not an efficient method.
Is there any better method?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The function you want is [`lua_gettable`](https://www.lua.org/manual/5.4/manual.html#lua_gettable).

First, push the table, then the key you want to check. Then you should be able to do `gettable(L, -2) != LUA_TNIL`.

Answer (score 3):

Simply check if `yourtable[yourkey]` is `nil`

You always put a key-value pair into a table. No value, no key.

Comment: Is there any C api that could do the same thing? `lua_rawgetp()` seems not work.

Comment: please update your question and add your code. "seems not to work" is not very informative